# Passing a parameter to a style for a datatrigger value (in WPF)

Tags: wpf, parameter-passing, datatrigger, wpf-style

I wrote a style to highlight some buttons depending on which Tab is selected, so I binded the `DataTrigger` to the SelectedIndex of the TabControl.

The style code is the following:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="MainPageToolMenuButtonIdx0">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=TabsProgrammingReport}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource BorderColorAccent}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource BorderColorAccent}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

This works correctly, however I would like to be able to pass a parameter to the style to set the `Value` of the `DataTrigger`.
I tried to bind the `Value` to the `Tag` property, however it is not working.

At the moment, I am forced to create multiple styles with different `Values="x"`.

Instead, I would like to have just a single style, and to write something like:

```
    <Button Style="{StaticResource MainPageToolMenuButtonIdx}" TagToSetValue="1" ... />
```

Is this possible?